Negative Correlation Fallacy
This is inspired by epsiode 4 of season 4 of Curb Your Enthusiasm. A major part of the plot of this episode is the weatherman, who just so happens to predict thunder storms when it is in fact very sunny out so nobody plays golf at his golf club on the same days as him.
This had me wondering; Say your weatherman is very bad. He has no clue how the weather works and is simply randomly guessing at the weather. Let $S$ be the random variable denoting the amount of sun on a given day, and let $W$ be the random variable denoting the prediction the weatherman makes as to how much sun there will be. Where a negative value means that it will rain and the magnitude denotes how much rain there will be.
Say I record multiple outcomes of S and W, and find that there is a very strong negative correlation between the two.
Say that I am wondering whether or not I should go golfing tomorrow and the weatherman predicts heavy rain; Should I go? Is there some sort of fallacy involved in using the so-far negative correlation to predict, that it will in fact be very sunny tomorrow?
